# Regexp group not excluding dots

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I have the following string: `div.classOneA.classOneB#idOne`

Trying to write a regexp which extracts the classes (classOneA, classOneB) from it. I was able to do this but with [Lookbehind assertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions) only.

It looks like this:

```
'div.classOneA.classOneB#idOne'.match(/(?<=\.)([^.#]+)/g)
> (2) ["classOneA", "classOneB"]
```

Now I would like to archive this without the lookbehind approach and do not really understand why my solution's not working.

```
'div.classOneA.classOneB#idOne'.match(/\.([^.#]+)/g)
> (2) [".classOneA", ".classOneB"]
```

Thought that the grouping will solve my problem but all matching item contains the dot as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to expand you regex. you can simply `map` on results and replace `.` with empty string

```js
let op = 'div.classOneA.classOneB#idOne'.match(/\.([^.#]+)/g)
         .map(e=> e.replace(/\./g,''))

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a good way in Javascript to both match multiple times (/g option) and pick up capture groups (in the parens). Try this:

```
var input = "div.classOneA.classOneB#idOne";
var regex = /\.([^.#]+)/g;

var matches, output = [];
while (matches = regex.exec(input)) {
    output.push(matches[1]);
}
```

Comment: You got there just ahead of me :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is because with `g` modifier you get all matching substrings but not its matching groups (that is as if `(...)` pairs worked just like `(?:...)` ones.

You see. Whithout `g` modifier:

```
> 'div.classOneA.classOneB#idOne'.match(/\.([^.#]+)/)
[ '.classOneA',
  'classOneA',
  index: 3,
  input: 'div.classOneA.classOneB#idOne',
  groups: undefined ]
```

With `g` modifier:

```
> 'div.classOneA.classOneB#idOne'.match(/\.([^.#]+)/g)
[ '.classOneA', '.classOneB' ]
```

In other words: you obtain all matches but only the whole match (0 item) per each.

There are many solutions:

1. Use *LookBehind* assertions as you pointed out yourself.
2. Fix each result later adding `.map(x=>x.replace(/^\./, ""))`
3. Or, if your input structure won't be much more complicated than the example you provide, simply use a cheaper approach:

   ```
   > 'div.classOneA.classOneB#idOne'.replace(/#.*/, "").split(".").slice(1)
   [ 'classOneA', 'classOneB' ]
   ```
4. Use `.replace()` + callback instead of `.match()` in order to be able to access capture groups of every match:

   ```
   const str = 'div.classOneA.classOneB#idOne';
   const matches = [];
   str.replace(/\.([^.#]+)/g, (...args)=>matches.push(args[1]))
   console.log(matches); // [ 'classOneA', 'classOneB' ]
   ```

I would recommend the third one (if there aren't other possible inputs that could eventually break it) because it is much more efficient (actual regular expressions are used only once to trim the '#idOne' part).

Comment: Wow, this fourth solution is quite a tricky one. Wouldn't thought to use replace this way. Thanks for the effort even though I've accepted an answer already.

Comment: I did it just for fun :-) Even though your question could seem a premature optimisation it's also true that there can be strong reasons to avoid lookbehind approaches: First because *lookarround* operations are ones of the most expensive ones in regular expression implementations so in code that will be executed too often it's a good idea to avoid them.

Comment: …on the other hand, just for that reason, they had been unavailable in javascript until (if I'm not wrong) ES6, so if your code needs to run in older javascript engines, lookarround approaches aren't a viable option.

Comment: I hadn't time to do it, but the *replace* approach can be generalized implementing a *mathcString()* function or even overloading String *.match()* method (which I don't advice to do so because it is an antipattern) but it could be an interesting exercise…

Answer (score 0):

If you know you are searching for a text containing `class`, then you can use something like

```
'div.classOneA.classOneB#idOne'.match(/class[^.#]+/g)
```

If the only thing you know is that the text is preceded by a dot, then you must use lookbehind.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will work without lookbehind assertion:

```
'div.classOneA.classOneB#idOne'.match(/\.[^\.#]+/g).map(item => item.substring(1));
```

Lookbehind assertion is not available in JavaScript recently.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on using regex - particularly in Javascript - but after some research on MDN I've figured out why your attempt wasn't working, and how to fix.

The problem is that using `.match` with a regexp with the `/g` flag [will ignore capturing groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Return_value). So instead you have to use the [.exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) method on the regexp object, using a loop to execute it multiple times to get all the results.

So the following code is what works, and can be adapted for similar cases. (Note the `grp[1]` - this is because the first element of the array returned by `.exec` is the entire match, the groups are the subsequent elements.)

```js
var regExp = /\.([^.#]+)/g
var result = [];
var grp;
while ((grp = regExp.exec('div.classOneA.classOneB#idOne')) !== null) {
  result.push(grp[1]);
}
console.log(result)
```